# Microsoft flow not triggering when new email is arrived

Tags: automation, powerapps, power-automate

I'm trying to automate a flow. The trigger action is done when a new email arrives in the outlook 365. I'm trying to read new email. But unfortunately the flow is not getting started.

Gone through many online articles but not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, my inbox had some rules. After removing, it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same issues what 'rules' on inbox did you change?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through the log to try and determine why the item is not executing?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. The issue is my inbox had some rules. After removing, it worked.